# Create Direct3D surface with aligned memory?

Tags: c++, c, directx, direct3d

I'm creating a Direct3D surface in system memory, then blitting some data into it, locking with `LockRect` and accessing the pixel data. I need the buffer that `LockRect`  returns to be aligned to page size (4096 bytes). 
Is there a way to force DirectX to allocate surface memory aligned? Thanks

Comment: What has `LockRect` to do with it? You tell it the buffer, and it locks it. You need to deal with it earlier. Can you copy the buffer data that DirectX gives you to a buffer aligned as you need? Or if you are supplying such a buffer, pass one that is aligned to your requirement?

Comment: You are apparently confusing this with other API. IDirect3DTexture9::LockRect returns a pointer to the buffer. I cannot copy to another buffer - it's too much performance overhead.

Comment: Why do you need it to be aligned to page size?

Comment: I'm transferring the data to the hardware via DMA, and that would improve the performance

Comment: Directly to the GPU from another device? A `memcpy` should not really have much impact even if your doing a fullscreen buffer every frame, and Direct3D puts the LockRect/Map buffer where it is efficient for itself (some control with creation and lock flags).